# Is there any way to report an abusive user?

Tags: feature-request, abuse

Is there anyway to report an abusive user, or can I just flag abusive posts?

Comment: How can you complain about abusive users while writing comments like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12406/how-to-deal-with-repeated-abuse/12409#12409), effectively insulting everyone on these sites who take the time to be a moderator?

Comment: I can also note that I had to flag several of this users posts as offensive: http://stackoverflow.com/users/122299/ It's evidently the same user. This after he heaped abuse over me, after recommending him to explain what "does not work" meant, instead of asking for someone who had had the same problem. He has now gone on a campaign to give me as many minuses he can. Good advertising for his company, I think... :-/ @Robert: maybe you should just stop being offended by people asking you to clarify your questions?

Answer (score 16):

You can only flag abusive posts.  We don't want to see a flag where you're *describing* a user as abusive.  We want to see exactly what they did.

Comment: If I have to flag a comment from a mod, who gets to review it, the same mod?

Answer (score 8):

Flag one of the abusive posts as "Requires Moderator attention", and describe the issue in the resulting text box. Alternatively, write to the team at `team@stackoverflow.com` (using the **contact us** link at the bottom of all pages).

Comment: Contacting team@stackoverflow.com id futile. Tried that in vain. Just useless copy paste answers with no connection to the problem at hand.